# How to set the client certificate for AWS API gateway deployment stage using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I am in the process of automating API gateway deployment using AWS CLI commands.

The cli command used to deploy an API goes like this.

```
aws apigateway create-deployment \
               --rest-api-id abcd1234 \
               --stage-name v1 \
               --variables elbDomain=xxx.yyy.zzz.io
```

Unfortunately, do not understand what would be the command to configure client certificate for that stage.

> Through API gateway UI you can achieve that and can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html#configure-api).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got the following answer from AWS technical support and it works
>   fine as expected. Also, they promised about updating their
>   documentation.

**Answer:**

I understand that you are trying to automate the process of API Gateway deployment using AWS CLI commands but you are not able to find configure Client Certificate for the stage.

There is no way to configure Client certificate using “create-deployment” command directly. After executing “create-deployment” command you need to use “update-stage” command to add client certificate as follows: 
[+] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-usage.html

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id API_ID --stage-name STAGE_NAME --patch-operations '[{"op":"replace","path":"/clientCertificateId","value":"CERTIFICATE_ID"}]'
```

If you want to generate new certificate, we can use “generate-client-certificate” command. 
[+] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/generate-client-certificate.html

I kindly apologize for the inconvenience that this is not mentioned clearly in our documentation. I will request to our documentation team regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use aws apigateway update-domain-name.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-domain-name.html

Comment: Thanks. But my question was about updating the stage with certificate Id. I got a reply from AWS help desk and I will update it here.